# How to filter products according to price with different currencies?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a products table which has all the necessary fields for any table that describes a product. I can add a product to this table with any price and currency e.g.:

```
name    , Price, Currency    
football, 10   , US dollar
jacket  , 10   , Euros
shirt   , 20   , Pounds
watch   , 30   , Euros     
pants   , 35   , Pounds
```

---

As you can see each product is added with its price and the currency that it was set to. my problem comes when I want to do a filter using PHP or Mysql directly (whatever works) for products that are in the price range of e.g. 5 to 20 dollars or 20 to 35 Pounds

something like this form:

```
From:
<input name="price_from" type="text" />
To:
<input name="price_to" type="text" />
Currency:
<select class="element select medium" id="element_3" name="currency">
  <option selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">Dollar</option>
  <option value="2">Pound</option>
  <option value="3">Euro</option>
</select>
```

And this will search all products regardless of the currency it is set to. How can i do that? i thought about converting the currency when the user saves the product but the problem with that is currency exchange rate keeps on changing endlessly. and selecting all the products then calculate the exchange rate then filtering depending the the rage that was given is not a good solution, especially when you have a very big database of products.

Comment: The "US Euro", the new global über-currency? ;P

Comment: how to use an online currency exchange api ?

if you can I ll post an answer for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea could be to calculate the currency exchange rate at the moment you do the query. For example, you  want to select all items between 1 US Dollar and 2 US Dollar.  Use a web service to calculate those values in other currencies. That way you will have something like:

Range:

- 1 and 2 US Dollar
- 0.4 and 0.7 Pounds
- 3 and 5 US Euro

And use those values to query the table.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Convert the values when querying, then sort, then print into a table.

Answer (score 0):

i just realize now (me also wanted same thing to do) create a new column in price table and update it with a currency constant -- keeping in mind one primary currency (euro in these case) example:
lets estimate dollar as 1.04 of a Euro

1. price      currency      sort_price       sort_currency ( just to be
   more clearly)
2. 10           USD            10.4              EUR
3. 12           Eur            12                EUR

and now we can sort easy by column sort_price all in eur

Next make 2 update command for mysql to update USD price in column sort_price and for EUR also.

Or can make a page in administration page to update sort_price by click of a button, and need php cod there to be made.

code:

if (isset($_POST['sort_price_act'])) {
        $price_new_sdf ='';

```
    $price_ron_select_query ="SELECT price, currency, id FROM table ORDER BY id ASC";   

    $price_ron_select = mysql_query($price_ron_select_query) or die("PPPPPPP".mysql_error());



    while ($price_ssss = mysql_fetch_array($price_ron_select, MYSQL_BOTH)) {

        if($price_ssss['currency'] == 'RON'){   

        $price_new_sdf = round($price_ssss['price'] / 4.81,2);


        mysql_query("UPDATE produse SET sort_price = '".$price_new_sdf."' WHERE id = '".$price_ssss['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());   


        }
        if($price_ssss['currency'] == 'EUR'){   

        $price_new_sdf = $price_ssss['price'];

        //echo $price_new_sdf.' EUR + id = '.$price_ssss['id'].'<br>';

        mysql_query("UPDATE produse SET sort_price= '".$price_new_sdf."' WHERE id = '".$price_ssss['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());        

        //$sort_priceuri = mysql_query($sort_priceuri_query) or die("VVVVVV".mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

}

```
    <tr>            
          <td width="250" align="center" style="background:#F63"><form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onSubmit="return confirm ('ACTUALIZE sort_price in EUR ?')">
        <input type="submit" name="sort_price_act" value="SORT NEW PRICE">
        </form>
        </td>       

    </tr>
```

ALl price updated works like a charm :)